# Script at specified location: scripts/register_with_elb.sh failed to complete in 3600 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I got error aws code deploy error at the application start lifecycle as "Script at specified location: scripts/register_with_elb.sh failed to complete in 3600 seconds".Actually new code deployed but failed to attach the instance to the loadbalancer.I attached the instance and issue got fixed.On next deployment got succecceeded without error.How I can fix this issue.I have jenkins server uses to trigger to code deploy and repository also in aws code commit

Comment: Please include the contents of what is being executed in the file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like register_with_elb.sh is your own custom script, presumably taken from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-elastic-load-balancing.html) tutorial.

Without knowing exactly what the contents are its hard to know why it might timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Check these log files on the EC2 instance [1] to find out what went wrong with the script execution:

```
LINUX 
*** /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-group-ID/deployment-ID/logs/scripts.log
*** /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
*** /tmp/codedeploy-agent.update.log
WINDOWS 
*** C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\log\codedeploy-agent-log.txt
*** C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\deployment-group-ID\deployment-ID\logs\scripts.log
*** C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeployUpdater\log\codedeploy-agent.updater.log
```

[1] Connecting to your Linux instance using SSH - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 0):

if it "failed to attach the instance to the loadbalancer", then you probably need to check healthchecks.

It is a property of Target groups for Load balancer. On a group details tab you can find `path`, `Success codes` and practically all you need.

That is how `Load Balancer` knows, that the instance is fine to be "attached".